# On Building flutter apk for release no login and registration

Tags: api, flutter, build, apk, emulation

I am trying to build an app and the app is running fine on the emulator ( Sign in and Sign Up are working fine with the API) but when I build the app for release and install it on the device, the API does not work (can not Sign Up and Sign In). Any help on this.

Comment: Please run the app on a physical device also and tell us the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign your release build. After signing that build, take the SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys used to sign that APK, and add them to your firebase console if you are using firebase.

If you aren't using firebase, you need to post more details regarding your error. It is most likely due to `Cleartext HTTP traffic`. and you need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml did solve the issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're most welcome! I've been there and it drove me crazy, this became a first thing to check when something works in debug but not release mode, when it comes to handling internet requests. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Looks you need to add the internet permission to your main manifest file.

Put this in your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Your manifest should look like this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <application ...
</manifest>
```

The internet permission is included in the debug manifest file by default and that's why your internet works for debug builds. This is because it

> allows Internet access during development to enable communication
> between Flutter tools and a running app.

[Source](http://allows%20Internet%20access%20during%20development%20to%20enable%20communication%20between%20Flutter%20tools%20and%20a%20running%20app.)